# Cakephp and JQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.2

This is killing me. I'm using JQuery 1.10.2 and Cakephp 2.2 and I want to do a GET from javascript. This is my code:

Javascript:

```
  var arg='/sites/fechas/10-02-2013';
  $.get(arg, function(data) {
     console.log(":" + data);
  });
```

CakePHP code (SitesController.php):

```
  public function fechas($fecha_reserva) {
     $this->autoRender = false;
     $fechas = $this->Informacion->find('count', array(
        'conditions' => array(
           'Informacion.fechas' => str_replace('-', '/', $fecha_reserva))
     ));
     return json_encode($fechas);
  }
```

From chrome developer tools

```
Request URL:http://my.web.com/sites/fechas/10-02-2013
Request Headers view parsed
GET http://my.web.com/sites/fechas/10-02-2013 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://my.web.com/reserva
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36
```

If I write the url in the browser I get a response (just a number). But from javascript I get nothing.

Comment: try echo json_encode($fechas); exit; instead of return

Comment: @hex4 Thanks. Nop, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view. Don't return directly from the Controller.
You can either:

- Use [data views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) (from cake > 2)
- render an empty view in an empty layout

The data views approach is very good however you will need todo some setup as described in the link - [parseExtensions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router%3a%3aparseExtensions), add the [RequestHandlerComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html#RequestHandlerComponent), etc. It is cleaner than the second option. Check the documentation and decide which one is for you.
The second option is the "old way to do it". Anyway if you want to do it the by the second way this is what you need to do:

- Create an `ajax.ctp` layout file under `View/Layouts`. Can be called whatever you like
- Have ONLY the `content_for_layout` display in it: `<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>`
- Create a view: `<?php echo json_encode($fechas);?>`
- Include the `RequestHandler` component if you are not getting the right headers
- In your controller after you get the data:

  `$this->set('fetchas', $fechas);`

  `$this->render('your_view's_name_here')`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it.